# Format integer number with . as thousand separator and no decimals

Tags: asp.net, decimal, number-formatting, digit-separator

I want to print a number with no decimals and a `.` as the thousand separator.
All the example I could Google have a `,` as a thousands separator.

I've set the `CultureInfo` to "nl-NL"

So 3200 should be shown as 3.200

I tried:

```
"3200".ToString("N2")  
"3200".ToString("#.###")
"3200".ToString("0:0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use  "nl-NL" then N0 should do it, try this:

```
    decimal num = 3200;
    num.ToString("N0");
```